# Wrapping functions in c++

Tags: c++

I have a function `executor` which is called with function pointer and a general function `origin` which I wan't to pass with different parameters `a` and `b` to the `executor`. How can it be done?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>

void executor(float (*f)(float)) {
  float x = 1.;
  std::cout << (*f)(x) << std::endl;
}

float original(float x,float a,float b) {
  return a*x + b;
}

//// Works as expected

float a = 1;
float b = 2;

float wrapped(float x) {
  return original(x,a,b);
}

void call_executor_global() {
  executor(wrapped);
}

//// FIRST TRY

// void call_executor_func(float a, float b) {

//   float wrapped(float x) {
//     return original(x,a,b);
//   }
//   executor(wrapped);
// }

//// SECOND TRY

// struct Wrapper {
//   float a;
//   float b;

//   float func(float x) {
//     return original(x,a,b);
//   }
// };

// void call_executor_struct(float a, float b) {

//   Wrapper wrapped;
//   wrapped.a = a;
//   wrapped.b = b;

//   executor(wrapped.func);

// }


int main()
{
  call_executor_global();
  // call_executor_func(1,2);
  // call_executor_struct(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Better use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) than raw function pointers.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `std::bind()` or use lambdas rather than write your `wrapped()` functions

Comment: You can't do it with that signature for `executor`. Can you change it?

Comment: In real life situation executor is loaded from external library

Comment: how about passing an int to specify how many params and a pointer to an array of floats?

Comment: It looks like std::bind() is going to work when `wrapped` function and `origin` have the same return types. Which will work for part of my real life situation

Comment: Do you still want help with it?

Comment: Try switching the design around.  Instead of passing objects to an executor, have the objects implement an executor method (make it virtual in a base class).

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how std::bind makes new function's signature (types of output and input arguments)

Comment: Also I would appreciate solution without C++11 because it slows down the compilation a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap a function using several methods. It is easier if you make executor a function template.

```
template <typename F>
void executor(F f) {
  float x = 1.;
  std::cout << f(x) << std::endl;
}
```

**Use a global function**

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;

float wrapped(float x) {
  return original(x,a,b);
}

void call_executor_global1() {
  executor(wrapped);
}
```

**Use a lambda function**

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;

void call_executor_global2() {
  executor([](float x) {return original(x, a, b);});
}
```

**Use a functor**

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;

void call_executor_global3() {
   struct wrapper
   {
      float operator()(float x) { return original(x, a, b); }
   };
  executor(wrapper());
}
```

See all of them working at http://ideone.com/rDKHC1.

Comment: So if I wrap my library function as function template I can call it with functor, is it so? This looks like one which could work for me :)

Comment: Ahh, It looks like that in templated function I would not get function pointer for passing to external library :/

Comment: @JānisErdmanis, In that case, your only option is to create a global function that acts as a wrapper around the function you wish to call.

Comment: In C is it possibel to change gloabal variables `a` and `b` locally in function?